# Program ending when reaching getline

Tags: c++, getline

I am using C++ for this program, but every time the program reaches `getline(cin, orders)` it exits with `"Process finished with exit code 11"`. I can't seem to figure out why `getline()` won't read the string. I tried using `cin.ignore();` but that didn't work.

This is a part of my code:

```
while (cin >> tableNum){
    cin >> input;
    if (input[0] == 'P'){

        partyNum = stoi(input.substr(1));

        if (partyNum > tables[tableNum].getMaxSeats())
            cout << "Sorry, max " << tables[tableNum].getMaxSeats() << " in Table " << tableNum << "!" << endl;

        else if (tables[tableNum].getStatus() == IDLE){
            tables[tableNum].setPartyNum(partyNum);
            tables[tableNum].setStatus(SEATED);
            cout << "Party of " << partyNum << " assigned to Table " << tableNum << endl;
            continue;
        }

        else
            cout << "Table " << tableNum << " already occupied!" << endl;
    }
    if (input == "O"){
        cout << "hi";
        getline (cin, orders);

        if (tables[tableNum].getStatus() == SEATED) {
            orderItems = tables[tableNum].setPartyOrder(orders);
            cout << orderItems << " items ordered for Table " << tableNum << endl;
        }
```

Here is a sample screen of the input and output:

```
1 P2
Party of 2 assigned to Table 1
1 O C3
hi
Process finished with exit code 11
```

Comment: What is `orders`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: orders is just a string variable

Comment: Pop quiz: when `(cin >> tableNum)` evaluatex to `false`, what must be the state of the input stream for this to evaluate to `false` and the `while` loop to stop? And, given the established state of the input stream, how exactly do you expect `std::getline` to do anything at all, any more?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the while loop will stop when a character is entered instead of an integer. The user is prompted to enter "C" when they want the program to stop

Comment: I didn't ask when the while loop will stop, but what must be the state of the input stream when that happens. "State of the input stream" means something very specific. See your C++ textbook for more information. When you figure out what the state of the input stream must be, why `std::getline` is not doing anything should be very obvious.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Would you mind explaining what you mean by state of the input stream a bit? I tried looking it up on my own but don't seem to understand what you mean

Comment: Well, wherever you read about what `while (cin >> tableNum)` is, and how it works, or perhaps what `if (cin >> tableNum)`  means and how it works, that should've explained to you the concept of the stream state. Take a step back and ask yourself, how does entering "C" make `while (cin >> tableNum)` stop the while loop. How is one connected to the other? There must be a logical explanation. For example: with `if (a > b)`, the result of the comparison is true if `a > b`, and false otherwise. Well, how does `cin >> tableNum` translate to true or false? How does that work? Answer: stream state.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik are you referring to the fact that std::istream lets an input stream be converted into a boolean?

Comment: Yes, now go read up how it does that, and you will find an explanation that it's false when the stream is in a failed state. And when the stream is in a failed state, as it must be for the `while` loop to terminate, a subsequent `std::getline` doesn't do anything. The stream has failed. So, again, you just answered your own question, as to why your `std::getline` doesn't do anything. Because the stream is in a failed state. The End.